# Create Instance of a class from interface which it implements

Tags: c#, .net, factory, unit-of-work

Hi I am trying to build a generic UoWFactory which creates a UnitOfWork(there will be one default unitofwork and multiple custom implementaitons as well). So far I was able to create factory method which creates default UoW and returns it. I have modify the following method to return specified UoW depending on the parameter passed.

Current implementation

```
private BaseResult<IUnitOfWork> GetUnitOfWorkByCompiledModel<IUnitOfWork>(DbCompiledModel compiledModel)
{
    return new BaseResult<IUnitOfWork>
    {
        Payload = new DbUnitOfWork(_context, _dbRepository, _mapper, _entityMapper)
    };
}
```

I wish to have something like this

```
private BaseResult<TUoW> GetUnitOfWorkByCompiledModel<IUnitOfWork>(DbCompiledModel compiledModel) where TUoW :Class
{
    return new BaseResult<TUoW>
    {
        //Create instance of type TUoW where TUoW can be IUnitOfWork, ICustomUnitOfWork etc
        //DbUnitOfWork implements IUnitOfWork and CustomUnitOfWork implements ICustomUnitOfWork
        //All the TUoW will have constructors with identical parmeters
    };
}
```

Create an instance of class is straight forward

```
Activator.CreateInstance (Type type, object[] args);
```

But if I pass Interface type as a parameter how to create instance of DbUnitOfWork or CustomUnitOfWork.
eg:-

```
GetUnitOfWorkByCompiledModel<IUnitOfWork>(compiledModel);
GetUnitOfWorkByCompiledModel<ICustomUnitOfWork>(compiledModel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Parameterless constructors

What you want is possible, except for one thing: **you can't use non-default constructors with generic type arguments**. You can't avoid that.

Part of the issue here is that you can't enforce specific constructor method signatures from an interface, so there is no way to guarantee that all implementation of `IUnitOfWork` are going to have the same constructor.

The simplest solution here is to step away from using constructors and instead use object initialization:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    Foo Foo { get; set; }
}

private BaseResult<TUnitOfWork> GetUnitOfWorkByCompiledModel<TUnitOfWork>(DbCompiledModel compiledModel) where TUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, new()
{
    return new BaseResult<TUnitOfWork>
    {
        Payload = new TUnitOfWork()
                  {
                      Foo = myFoo
                  };
    };
}
```

I think this suits your expectations while being a minimal change.

---

### Resolving interfaces

> But if I pass Interface type as a parameter how to create instance of DbUnitOfWork or CustomUnitOfWork. eg
>
> `GetUnitOfWorkByCompiledModel<IUnitOfWork>(compiledModel);`
> `GetUnitOfWorkByCompiledModel<ICustomUnitOfWork>(compiledModel);`

If you intend to use interface types without concrete types, then the above answer is incomplete.

Regardless of the generic type issue, if you want to resolve an interface into a concrete type, you need to register which concrete type you want to use.

This is most commonly done via a Dependency Injection framework. These framework ask you to register all necessary types, e.g. a .NET Core example:

```
services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, MyUnitOfWork>();
services.AddTransient<ICustomUnitOfWork, MyCustomUnitOfWork>();
```

And the framework will then use this registration to automatically fill in constructor parameters for you:

```
public class Example
{
    public Example(ICustomUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        
    }
}
```

The good practice approach here requires you to thread this dependency injection through your entire framework so you never need to call any constructor explicitly (and instead have the DI framework do it for you).

It is possible to use a [service locator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern), which is essentially a DI framework that you call at-will. A small example of usage would be:

```
private BaseResult<TUnitOfWork> GetUnitOfWorkByCompiledModel<TUnitOfWork>(DbCompiledModel compiledModel) where TUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, new()
{
    var uow = myServiceLocator.Get<TUnitOfWork>();
    uow.Foo = myFoo;

    return new BaseResult<TUnitOfWork>
    {
        Payload = uow;
    };
}
```

This creates an instance of whichever concrete type was registered to the interface you're using as the generic parameter.

However, **service locators are generally considered to be an anti-pattern**, and I would strongly suggest that you avoid favor a cleaner IoC approach than this.

I can't elaborate fully on dependency injection in scope of a single StackOverflow answer. I suggest you look up dependency injection as it does exactly what you're expecting (getting a concrete type by referencing an interface)

Comment: That is really a great solution. But in my scenario it would form a cyclic dependency. is there a different way even if complicated.

Comment: Can I pull out the class implementing the interface and create an instance using reflection.

Comment: @HarishNIngeGowda: How would this create a cyclic dependency? Nothing in the question/answer contains a cyclic dependency.

Comment: There are two packages 1. contracts(containig interfaces) and 2. Domain(containing implementaitons of these interfaces along with _context, _dbRepository, _mapper, _entityMapper). unitofwork depends on contracts. And for the above to work Contracts should depend on Domain. that would make cyclic. I did not think that this information would be relevant to put it in question.

Comment: Also putting _context, _dbRepository, _mapper, _entityMapper in IUnitOfWork would expose them to outside world which I do not want it happen.

Comment: @HarishNIngeGowda: Contracts should not depend on the domain. I suspect you've misplaced some of the classes/interfaces or have not abstracted all your concrete types into the necessary interfaces for a contract/domain segregation to work as intended. The issue is not apparent based on your description. It sounds like you have some larger scale architectural issues which we can't cover in this question.

Comment: @HarishNIngeGowda: The more you talk the more I'm convinced that you need to look up dependency injection. A good DI framework tackles all the problems you're mentioning, though depending on your current codebase it may require a larger rework.

Comment: We are already using SimpleInjector for dependency injection. I will go ahead and use SimpleInjector to instantiate the interface. Your answer is now complete. Thank you for all the trouble.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201409/discussion-between-harish-ninge-gowda-and-flater).

Answer (score 0):

This will be work if DbUnitOfWork Class has right name of values

**What you want to change**

```
Payload = new DbUnitOfWork(_context, _dbRepository, _mapper, _entityMapper);
```

**Change as**

```
Payload = new DbUnitOfWork() {
    context = _context, 
    dbRepoitory = _dbRepository,
    mapper = _mapper,
    entityMapper = _entityMapper
};
```

hope this work.

Comment: I have to create instance from interface

Comment: @HarishNIngeGowda Be careful how you phrase what you want. As I understand it, you don't want to create an instance from an interface, but rather from a type (generic class type) which **implements** said interface.

Comment: could you post DbUnitOfWork class?

Comment: @Arphile: The specifics of the `DbUnitOfWork` should be irrelevant (other than knowing it implements `IUnitOfWork`) since the generic code should be agnostic of the specific type that is used as the generic type.